# Spring Test No qualifying bean of type с использование JavaConfig

Tags: java, spring, test-driven-development

недавно начал пользоваться JavaConfig в Spring. И сейчас решил попировать провести тесты, без использования xml.

Открыл доку, сделал все как надо, благо сильно не отличается.
прописал аннотации необходимые и параметры

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppInit.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
```

Далее делаю autowired необходимого Бина

```
@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

запускаю тест и получаю ошибку No qualifying bean of type.

MyBean помечен как @Component и в конфете не описан.

Я уже прописывал статический класс в классе теста и в нем описывал Бин
Таким образом

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppInit.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyBeanTest {

@Configuration
static class ContextConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
}

@Autowired
private MyBean myBean;
```

Не помогло, и аннотацию @Qualifier ставил, прописывал уже сам Бин с именем определенным в AppInit.class, ничего не помогает.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, может я что-то не дописал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось еще проще, я забыл аннотацию @WebAppConfiguration.
Так же прописал все файлы конфигов, и не пришло создавать тестовый файл конфига.
Так же нужно убрать параметр loader у аннотации ContextConfiguration

Вот как в итоге выгладит заголовок

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {
    AppInit.class,
    DBConfig.class,
    AppConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю надо явно проимпортировать ContextConfiguration класс в аннотации у себя в тесте.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {AppInit.class, MyBeanTest.ContextConfiguration.class}, loader = 
AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class MyBeanTest {
```

Тут такой же принцип как с xml - нужно либо явно описать какие файлы должны быть в тестовом контексте или же сконфигурировать автоматический импорт.

Вообще я бы убрал тестовый конфиг в отдельный класс и переименовал его (т.к. может пересекаться с аннотацией)

Comment: Спасибо, даже и не было намека, что его тоже туда надо, перенесу все в отдельный класс